# Could not load app built by Cordova if these three scripts included

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, shared-libraries

Somehow, if I include ANY of the following three libraries, the app won't load in my android phone (it will run in the browser though).

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=XXXXXXXXXX" async defer></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

It said "Application Error: The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)".

The app will load only if I were to remove ALL three libraries.

What should I do to include the three libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason: my WiFi lost its connection to the internet.